# How to retrieve records from database table in Laravel and prevent those which are expired

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

So I have a table in MySQL which looks like this

[image]

these are basically ads that are posted by users. Duration column in this table is about for how many days the User wants to show their ad. that means if user choose to post ad for 3 days i should not just show after 3 days that means it will expire after three days. Now i Want to retrieve only those records which are not expired.
I have searched a lot but could not find a way to do this. Kindly give me a solution or refer to a link where i can possibly find the solution.

Right now I am using this script to get the records with simple pagination

```
$items=Post::with('items','users')->paginate(12);
$categories = DB::table('item_categories')->get();
return view('search_post', compact('items','categories'));
```

Comment: Hint: If the expiration time is the start time plus the duration, then you want all records where the expiration time is in the future.

Comment: yes, i get that, but i can not find a way to do this

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Duration from `created_at` or `updated_at` OR maybe you should also have a `start_date` so you know when to start showing the ad. Lots of unknowns here

Comment: Or maybe you could have a `start_date` and a `finish_date` that you set when you originally enter the info about the ad and when it should be shown

Comment: this reference just gave me thought. I might be able to do it easy way by saving the date of expiration and then comparing it to the 'Created_at' column. thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed my table to this

[image: Changed Table to this]

And using this script

```
$items=Post::with('items','users')->where('duration','>=',\Carbon\Carbon::now() )->paginate(12);
$categories = DB::table('item_categories')->get();
return view('search_post', compact('items','categories'));
```

It is working perfectly. Thanks to every one.

Answer (score 0):

You should do an Where Clause with your paginate.

as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50903963/3808783

like:

```
$items=Post::with('items','users')
            ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->addDays(3))
            ->paginate(12);
```

Comment: how do i put that three in addDays() ?

Comment: you should change your table column name to "expiry" instead of duration. but you've already figured it out. please mark some answer as "Correct"

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon to do so. 
Simply add `duration` to `created_at` with Carbon `addDay($duration)` method.
Then return your posts where the result is >= to `today()`.